# C# conversion help needed

Tags: c#, console

Line2D.cs

```
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
  public  class Line2D
    {
    public String name; // any name
    public Point2d p1;
    public Point2d p2;
    public Line2D(Point2d p1, Point2d p2, String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
    public Point2d nearPoint(Point2d p)
    {
        double slope = (this.p2.y - this.p1.y);
        double coffX = slope;
        double coffY = -1;
        double const1= slope * this.p1.x - this.p1.y;

        //AX + BY=C
        //imaginary line perpendicular to line and passing through given point
        double slope1 = -1 * slope;
        double coffX1 = slope;
        double coffY1 = -1;
        double const2 = slope * this.p1.x - this.p1.y;
        double X = (const1 - const2) / (coffX - coffX1);
        double Y = coffX * X - const1;
        String Name = "nearPoint";
        Point2d P = new Point2d (X, Y,Name);
        return p;
    }
  }
 }
```

Point 2D.cs

```
    namespace ConsoleApp1
     {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public String name;
    public Point2d(double x,double y,string name)
    {
        this.x = x;

        this.y = y;

        this.name = name;
    }
}
 }
```

Program.cs

```
     namespace ConsoleApp1
   {
    class Program
     {
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("enter X cordinate of point:");
        double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enter Y cordinate of point:");
        double y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Point2d p = new Point2d(x,y,"nischal");
        Console.WriteLine("enter 1st point:"); //Line12
        Point2d p1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter 2nd point:"); //Line 14
        Point2d p2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Line2D l = new Line2D(p1,p2,"nischal"); // Line 16
    }
}
```

}

QUESTION : I want to make an object of Line2D and call its nearPoint method. But I am stuck with Line 12 Line 14 16. I want user to input value of p1 and p2 of data type which is Point2d p1 and Point2d p2 data type which goes through calculation on Line2D class. But I'm getting error during conversion at Line 12 and Line 14. Please some experts help me solve this. It's C# console application code.

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` gives you a string, parse the string to build your object instead.

Answer (score 1):

From `Console.ReadLine()` you get a `string`. I'm confused that you don't get a compiler error. In general you need to parse the point from the string. You can do it on several ways. Any time you need a function which takes a string and returns a Point2d

1) implement a cast operator in your `Point2D`. And call it from your code:

```
public class Point2d
{
    public static explicit operator Point2d(string stringRepresentation)
    {
        Point2d point;
        //parse point from string manually
        return d;
    }
}

static void Main (string[] args])
{
    Point2d myPoint = (Point2d) Console.ReadLine();
}
```

2) Implement a constructor which takes a string

```
public class Point2d
{
    public Point2d(string stringRepresentation)
    {
        //parse point from string manually
    }
}

static void Main (string[] args])
{
    Point2d myPoint = new Point2d (Console.ReadLine());
}
```

There are other ways possible. But i think these two are the best suited.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Point2d` needs two variables of type double and one of type string. So the easiest way would probably be to ask the user to input those values individually. Since the `Console.ReadLine()`-Method returns the user-input as string you have to parse the values for your `Point2d.x` and `Point2d.y`. You could do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p1x = RequestUserInput_Double("Enter 1st point x value:");
        var p1y = RequestUserInput_Double("Enter 1st point y value:");
        var p2x = RequestUserInput_Double("Enter 2nd point x value:");
        var p2y = RequestUserInput_Double("Enter 2nd point y value:");

        var p1 = new Point2d(p1x, p1y, "SomeName");
        var p2 = new Point2d(p2x, p2y, "SomeOtherName");
    }

    public static double RequestUserInput_Double(string requestString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(requestString);
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        double value;

        // Try to parse the user input into a double value
        while(!Double.TryParse(userInput, out value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid format. Please enter a valid double value:");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

You could also ask the user to input the names for the points, if you want to (and since those are strings, you would not need to cast them).

Of course you could do some fancy parsing of the user-input, so it would be possible to enter something like `2.0 4.0 MyPoint1` in a single line, but for the sake of simplicity I would just ask for every value individually.

Comment: your code isn't working var p2y = (double)Console.ReadLine(); (Error:cannot convert string to double);
var p2 = new Point2d(p2x, p2y, "SomeOtherName");
(error:cannot convert string to ConsoleApp1.Point2d);

Comment: Your code doesn't  even run .

Comment: I want to make object of Line2D (Point p1,Point p2, string name) where Point p1, point p2 is like data type.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot you can't just cast a string to a double in C#. I updated my example above and added a helper-method with some simple parsing for the user-input. This works for me. Please let me know, if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: You haven't yet answered my main question yet.  
I want to make object of Line2D (Point p1,Point p2, string name) where Point p1, point p2 is like data type. How to do so?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'where Point p1, point p2 is like data type'. But if you want to create a Line2D object from those two points, just do `var line = new Line2D(p1, p2, "someName");`

Comment: Thanks your idea works

Answer (score 0):

`ReadLine` gives you a `string`, which cannot be converted to `Point2D`.

To create a `Point2D` object using a string, you need to *parse* the string. First, let's decide on what format the user will enter the point's coordinates in. I would say the format `(x,y)` is the most user-friendly.

To parse `(x,y)`, we can use regular expressions,

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
var match = Regex.Match(userInput, @"\(([-\d.]+),\s+([-\d.]+)\)");
var x = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
var y = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

You can put this logic into a method and put the method alongside `Main`:

```
private static Point2D Point2DFromString(string s, string name) {
    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    var match = Regex.Match(userInput, @"\(([-\d.]+),\s+([-\d.]+)\)");
    var x = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
    var y = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
    return new Point2D(x, y, name);
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
Point2d p1 = Point2DFromString(Console.ReadLine(), "p1");
```

Comment: It works but during runtime while entering value I get : 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' to type 'System.IConvertible'.' 

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/hnbzhg

Comment: @NischalPrajapati oops! Typos! Edited now

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" error

Comment: I also stated how to make an object of Line2D too, can I have a full code ?